# Play the default notification sound on user settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to play the default push notification sound in my app, this is possible ? from my understanding i can play specific sound if i have the sound ID.
can i play the chosen "default" sound in my app ?

Answer (score 2):

You can play any sound that you want. By default we play the default notification sound only.

The payload should be like this

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Alert Message",
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "default"
  }
}
```

Just pass `"default"` in **sound** key.

If you want to play a custom push notification sound, pass the sound name with extension for example `"mynotifsound.caf"`in **sound** key and make sure the file with **mynotifsound.caf** should be present in app's bundle.

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Alert Message",
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "mynotifsound.caf"
  }
}
```